# textFieldDidEndEditing is called for only one text field

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, uitextfield

I have 3 `UITextField`s in my `UITableViewController`'s 3 cells.I have certain validation on `textFieldDidEndEditing` for the 3 `UITextField`s,  but it only runs when I edit on the 1st `UITextField` the code in `textFieldDidEndEditing` is called. What I want is that each time he edits an `UITextField`, the validation for atleast that field should happen, it does not happen when I edit and come out of the last two `UITextFields`, I edit the first `UITextField` does the validation for all 3 `UITextFields` happen.

I am developing for iOS 6.

Comment: Did you set the delegate for the remaining two textfields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have forgot to set the delegate for the remaining two fields . Check it .